# sqlite3 not flushing table

Tags: python, sqlite

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
with open('./mydb_tmp.sql', 'w') as f:
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM FLOWS'):
        print >>f, row
c.execute('DELETE FROM FLOWS;')
conn.close()
```

After that, all rows are still in mydb

Answer (score 6):

You need to commit the command.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()
with open('./mydb_tmp.sql', 'w') as f:
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM FLOWS'):
        print >>f, row
c.execute('DELETE FROM FLOWS;')
# Flush your commands to the db with conn.commit().
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Check the documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html